# Are strings (in string theory) able to rotate?

Tags: string-theory, rotation

I read in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/QCD_correspondence) Wikipedia article:

> In the late 1960s, experimentalists had found that hadrons fall into families called Regge trajectories with squared energy proportional to angular momentum, and theorists showed that this relationship emerges naturally from the physics of a rotating relativistic string.

This confuses me. What makes a rotating string distinguishable from a non-rotating one?

The string has no structure, so how can it rotate? I can imagine the string vibrating. But rotating...?

Who has something useful to say on this issue?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I was indeed thinking of closed strings (associated with gravity). String corresponding to elementary particles are always depicted as circular in Feynman diagrams, hence the confusion. But considering straight ones it's indeed not so hard to imagine. Because different points on this rotating string have different speeds (if it's even possible to envision one), the string will bend and maybe even form a nearly closed string. And what about the uncertainty principle coming into play? What influence has this on the strings form? I think we wrongly picture a meson con. to strings.

Comment: The can rotate. The difference is that they carry different quantum numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical string can of course rotate when its endpoints (if it is open) or the loop that it forms (if it is closed) rotate. This is just ordinary geometry.

However, the "spinning string" here likely refers not to this extrinsic notion of rotation of a classical string but to the idea of the [superstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superstring_theory), whose worldsheet fermions give it a notion of intrinsic spin similar to how worldline fermions give a particle a notion of intrinsic spin in a worldline formulation. The Neveu-Schwarz-Ramond superstring was indeed originally conceived to explain Regge trajectories.

Comment: Why do you say "likely"? Are you saying that the trajectory on a worldsheet "makes" a string rotate? And how come they are rotating at relativistic speeds?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Because I cannot read the mind of whoever wrote the Wiki article to be sure.

Comment: How is a superstring different from a classical one (apart from being supersymmetric). Or is the supersymmetry precisely what defines a superstring?